# MongoDB fields/keys limit per document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is there any limit for fields count per single MongoDB document? Didn't find anything about that in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/).

For example, if I have document that contains 1000 fields and fits 16Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It will work.

Fields are part of Documents. Mongo has only [document size limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) of 16Mb. As long as it fits in 16Mb, it's good.

But I suggest you to look at the need for these many fields in single document.